# Issue in importing large CSV file to Postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin

I am using postgresql 9.5. Trying to **import** data to a table through a **.csv** file(45 GB). I am using **pgAdmin III** to import the file. But it is throwing the following error:

> ../src/gtk/gauge.cpp(67): assert "0 <= m_gaugePos && m_gaugePos <=
>   m_rangeMax" failed in DoSetGauge(): invalid gauge position in
>   DoSetGauge()

[image]

and the **pgAdmin** client getting closed. When I am trying the same with a small .csv file, it is working fine.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I would recommend using `psql`, especially with this big files

Comment: @Vao, can you please explain, what are you recommending?

Comment: I suggest you running `psql -c "copy tablename from filename"` on command prompt

Comment: Solved the problem by query `"copy tablename FROM 'filename' DELIMITER '|' CSV" `. I was facing some problem in running the command on command prompt. What i was doing : 
**STEP 1:** sudo su - postgres.  
**STEP 2:** psql -c "copy tablename from filename" .  
but it was throwing syntax error.